# Nautilus fail for remote

Tags: nautilus, remote

I am testing remote desktop from Windows to Ubuntu 12.04 with ssh. I can get connected and commandline works ok. However, when I use "nautilus" to display the desktop of Ubuntu, it failed. But nautilus itself works no problem when I directly use it on Ubuntu, it can display the desktop. Anyone knows about this problem?

Thanks.

```
** (nautilus:9732): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=23357284be8dc03a3651b9e200000007 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
Could not parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

Answer (score 0):

have you used ssh -XC ? after that the command would be `dbus-launch nautilus --no-desktop --browser`